# Unable to install R packages from source in sun solaris. iconv in R cannot get current locale from ''

Tags: r, solaris, iconv

I am trying to install R packages from source in a sun solaris machine. When I use

`> install.packages('iterators', repo=NULL, type='source')`

I get the error

```
Error in iconv(lines, encoding, "UTF-8", sub = "byte") :
  unsupported conversion from '' to 'UTF-8'
```

I notice that the from field is empty ('') so I check the 
iconv {base} manual. It says

"All R platforms support "" (for the encoding of the current locale), "latin1" ..."

link : https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/iconv.html

So I try a conversion using iconv

```
>iconv('abc', '', 'utf-8')
```

I get the error

```
Error in iconv("abc", "", "utf-8") :
  unsupported conversion from '' to 'utf-8'
```

However on my local linux machine the same conversion works

```
> iconv('abc', '', 'utf-8')
[1] "abc"
```

Is there a particular reason why iconv from R on sun solaris cannot get current locale from ''? Or is there a workaround to install the packages?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Solaris  You need GNU `libconv` and `readline`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have installed GNU libiconv and readline, but the libiconv is installed in a different location since the admin did not want to replace the existing iconv. So I set the PATH system variable such that R can find the new iconv binary at the new new location. But R still uses the solaris iconv. Is this workaround doable? 

`>Sys.setenv(PATH = "<location of iconv>:<entire long old PATH>")`

`> system('iconv --version')
iconv (GNU libiconv 1.9)
Copyright ...`

`> iconv("abc", "", "ASCII")
Error in iconv("abc", "", "ASCII") :
  unsupported conversion from '' to 'ASCII'`

Comment: According to the page I linked, and if you read it, you need to set `R_LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I read that but was confused since I have R installed and trying to make it work. I am not compiling from source. New to this.

Comment: If you are not going to compile from source, I guess it will be very complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You are not mentioning the version of Solaris. On Solaris 10 iconv does not accept empty string ("") as a codeset specification. On Solaris 11 you can use "char" or "" for iconv to use the codeset of current locale. This is described in:

```
# man -s 3C iconv_open
```

Comment: Yes it was solaris 10. My bad. As @pascal mentioned the problem was that R was made to use GNU iconv. After I used (GNU) iconv from openCSW I was able to make the conversion work.